# What's the algorithm behind add() method in Java for ArrayList?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, addition

So I got a bit creative and wanted to re-create some methods in Java and I got stuck with `add()`.

My idea is to check first if we need more size then add (if we need).

After that copy the initial array and then shift the indexes and numbers in the array, but I frankly have no idea how to do that so that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Why would there be shifting?

Comment: If you use javap, you can reverse engineer the bytecode: `javap -v java.util.ArrayList`. That may help you see what it's doing under the covers.

Comment: Or you can just look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java?av=f).

Comment: @harold Isn't that logical? If I were just to add some element to certain index without shifting the rest I would just overwrite current element, or at least I think so.

Comment: @brajevicm well.. maybe? You could just change the index though, and not shift the contents

Comment: @harold So if I were to have `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and I want to `add(1,10)` without shifting I'd get `{1, 10, 3, 4}`, since there's no shifting I won't have all the elements from previous (original) array.

Comment: Oh the overload that takes an index. Fair enough. You should specify these things though, as you see it makes a big difference.

Comment: @harold Well that's what `add()` does.

Comment: @brajevicm no it isn't. It's what `add(index, element)` does. There is no `add` with no arguments, and the "inserting" `add` is the least common overload. The answer which you said was what you needed is also about the appending `add`.

Answer (score 4):

The logic is as much as this:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacity(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

you can see the hole java source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I needed.